# Select2 no fuciona dentro del una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, select2

tengo una tabla que contiene distintos elementos, uno de ellos debe ser un select usando Select2 para facilidar las busquedas.
Resulta que cuando le agrego las propiedades para convertirlo en un select de busqueda Select2, no funciona...este es mi codigo

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({ 
   placeholder: "Seleccione"
   });
   
});

function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
    document.getElementById(tagId).value = "";
}
</script>
<section class="content-header">
 <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>

 <!--<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a ui-sref="app.landing"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Inicio</a></li>
  <li class="active">Nueva Póliza</li>
 </ol>-->
</section>
<section class="content">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
   <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
     <h3 class="box-title">Documentos del Reclamo</h3>
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" title="Devolver Documentos" ng-disabled="!vm.sendmail" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="vm.retufiles()">Devolver Documentos
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" name="uiForm" ng-submit="vm.save(uiForm.$valid)" novalidate>
     <div class="box-body" style="overflow-x:scroll;">
      <div ng-if="vm.alerts" class="alert alert-{{alert.type}}" ng-repeat="alert in vm.alerts">
       <h4>{{alert.title}}</h4>
       <p>{{alert.msg}}</p>
      </div>
      
            <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 8px; overflow-x:scroll;">
                                  <tr ng-repeat="pline in vm.previouslines" style="height: 120px" ng-if = "vm.previouslines[$index].dispatched == '0' " >
                    <td style="height: 120px !important">

                                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10" style="height: 120px !important">
                           <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': uiForm.pdoc_type_id{{pline.id}}.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || uiForm.pdoc_type_id{{pline.id}}.$touched) }">
                           <label for="pdoc_type_id{{pline.id}}">Tipo de Documento</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" style='font-size: 14px; width: 150px;' ng-model="vm.previouslines[$index].id_doc_type" name="pdoc_type_id{{pline.id}}" ng-change="vm.changeDocType($index,2);" required >
                               <option style="font-size: 17px" ng-repeat="doc in vm.systemDocTypes" ng-value="{{doc.id}}" ng-selected="{{1 == doc.id}}">{{doc.name}}</option>
                           </select>
                                                <p class="help-block">Requerido.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
               </td>
               <td style="height: 120px !important">
                                     <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10" style="height: 120px !important" >
                           <div class="js-example-basic-single" ng-class="{ 'has-error': uiForm.pcurrency_id{{pline.id}}.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || uiForm.pcurrency_id{{pline.id}}.$touched) }" id="table">
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="vm.modalProvider()"  ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <label for="pdoc_type_id{{pline.id}}" class="control-label">Proveedor</label>
                                                <select  class="js-example-basic-single" style='font-size: 14px; width: 150px;' ng-model="vm.previouslines[$index].provider_id" placeholder="Seleccione" name="provider_id{{pline.id}}" required 
                                              ng-options="doc.id as doc.name for (key, doc) in vm.systemProviders">
                              <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
                               <option style="font-size: 17px" ng-repeat="doc in vm.systemProviders" ng-value="{{doc.id}}" >{{doc.name}}</option>
                           </select>
                          
                                                <p class="help-block">Requerido.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                    </td>
```

Pero al ejecutar la aplicacion, el select se ve normal, sin las funciones del select2. Que debo hacer ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Selec2 esta basado en Jquery, por lo tanto antes de ingresar el CDN de Select2 debes de poner antes el de Jquery.

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/huy3o6pk/)

Comment: Pero porque ocurre que si coloco el select fuera del table entonces si funciona el select2 ?

Comment: No sé a que te refieras exactamente con eso, pero tomé tu codigo y cerre algunos tags que faltaban de tu tabla e hice un select fuera de la tabla y deje los que estaban dentro y ambos funcionan correctamente [Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/gd9w7oxy/)

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios y tu interes. Pero creo que debor replantear el problema. La cuestion es, como hacer para generar select2 de manera dinamica?...Estoy trabajando con angular y laravel, y necesito en algun momento generar N select del tipo Select2 de manera dinamica.

Comment: Algo así, te servirá? [Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/14346/)